# Plugin options from FlexForms in TYPO3

Tags: php, plugins, typo3

I built an extension using extension builder and added a plugin for this. I would like to add plugin options at the time of adding the plugin to the page, which will determine the controller action for that page. Say I have two pages `List` and `Search`, I should be able to give the plugin option to choose `MyExtController->list` for `List` page and `MyExtController->search` for `Search` page.

So far I did this:

In my `ext_tables.php` :

```
$pluginSignature = str_replace('_','',$_EXTKEY) . 'myext';
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_myext.xml');
```

my FlexForm in `Configuration/FlexForms:`

```
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Function</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <switchableControllerActions>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Select function</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <items>
                                    <numIndex index="0">
                                        <numIndex index="0">List</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">MyExtController->list</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1">
                                        <numIndex index="0">Search</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">MyExtController->search</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </switchableControllerActions>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

Somehow, I think i'm missing something. This does not work. Am I doing it right ? I do not see any plugin options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the underscore in the `$pluginSignature` it should be:

```
$pluginSignature = str_replace('_','',$_EXTKEY) . '_myext'
//                                                 ^-here
```

Also keep in mind that `'_myext'` should be lower cased name of your plugin (no the ext) (that string which you register as a second argument of the `registerPlugin` method)